# How can i get a list of apps that use an Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

I have a number of Key Vaults in Azure, round 10. There are a number of app services and function apps that use these key vaults.
The issue is that a number of these key vaults are no longer used so how can i tell which apps are using a key vault ?  That is can i see which apps are accessing a key vault from the key vault itself ?

Comment: How would you like to get those details? Is it PowerShell or CLI or any other? @Melissa

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far. @Melissa

Comment: Powershell or from the portal ?

Comment: from the portal i went to Key Vault and then access policies.    Would that be adequate ?

Comment: Powershell would be good as i can confirm before deleting anything

Comment: If you went to access policies, you will be able to identify who are authorized to access the key vault but not about what are the linked app services. @Melissa

Comment: How did you link your key vaults with apps. Is it via app settings or service connector? @Melissa

Comment: i just went to access policies in the key vault and added the app .

Comment: Just that i want to see who acesses the vault before i delete it

Comment: Updated below in both views. @Melissa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get a list of apps that use an Azure Key Vault: -

As you are already doing, the applications or users details accessing the specific key vault can be checked under `key vault >> Access policies` through Portal.

[image]

***Use below PowerShell code to meet your requirement.***

```
$keyVault = "newvaultj"
$keyVaultdetails = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVault
$accesspolicies = $keyVaultdetails.accesspolicies
$accesspolicies.DisplayName
```

[image]

*If you are working on more than one number of key vaults, define an array of key vault strings and traverse through the array to retrieve the required details as given below.*

```
 $keyvaultarray = @("newvaultj","newvault2j")
 foreach($kv in $keyvaultarray){
   $kvinfo = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $kv
   $accesspolicies = $kvinfo.accesspolicies
     foreach($accesspolicy in $accesspolicies){
       $displaynames = $accesspolicy.DisplayName
   Write-Host "Linked applications are:  $($displaynames)"
       }
 }
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use [`az webapp connection list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/connection?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-connection-list) command to check the service connections from the apps (web app or function app) side.

*Portal path:* `Function App/Web App >> Settings >> Service Connector`

[image]

*Code view:*

```bash
$ids= (az webapp connection list -g xxxx -n newapj --query '[].targetService.id')
 if($ids -match "newvaultj"){ 
    Write-Host "specific key vault is linked to the app service"
    }else{
    Write-Host "Not linked"
     }
```

[image]